# Enter doesn't work when interactive command is launched in shell

Tags: zsh, line-breaks

After some actions in term enter stops working in with interactive commands in shell - I am still able to launch a command but if the command requires additional inputs line break is inserted at '^M'.

Example:

```
$ git add -p .
diff --git a/app/models/coupon.rb b/app/models/coupon.rb
index 39df1f3..736ea62 100644
--- a/app/models/coupon.rb
+++ b/app/models/coupon.rb
@@ -3,6 +3,7 @@ class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
   COUPON_PRECREATE_EXPIRATION_BUFFER = 5.days
   COUPON_PRECREATE_COUNT = 15

+  include CommonNamedScopes

   belongs_to :coupon_list
   #belongs_to :couponable, :polymorphic => true
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? y^M
```

(same problem can be achived when using `cat` for example) so it has no relation to `git`.

Can someone advice why this is happening?

iTerm2 Build 1.0.0.20120724

zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That generally is because a program changed the state of the terminal, but did not change it back.

Try running the `reset` command, and see if that fixes things.

Since you're using zsh, you could also use `ttyctl -f` to have zsh automatically reset terminal settings after commands are run. But don't use that before resetting the terminal first or zsh will freeze the settings in the broken state.